# How to install packaged app on Firefox for mobile?

Tags: android, firefox, web-applications, fennec

*How do I test-install a packaged (zip) app on Fennec?*

Device: Physical Android phone or Android emulator, I don't care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [mozilla-apk-cli](https://github.com/mozilla/apk-cli) using NPM:

```
npm install -g mozilla-apk-cli
```

Use it to generate a "debuggable" APK for your app from either a source directory or a URL to the mini-manifest:

```
mozilla-apk-cli /path/to/source/dir/ arbitrary-name.apk
mozilla-apk-cli http://example.com/path/to/mini/manifest.webapp arbitrary-name.apk
```

(Context-click > Inspect Element on the "Free" button in Marketplace to discover the mini-manifest URL for an app in the Marketplace.)

Install the APK on your Android device:

```
adb install -r arbitrary-name.apk
```

Launch the app on the device.  Look to the notification area for a notification about which port the remote debugger server is listening on.  Forward that port on your desktop, f.e. if the port is 12345:

```
adb forward tcp:12345 tcp:12345
```

Go to Web Developer > Connect… in Firefox on your desktop and connect to localhost at the forwarded port.  Commence debugging!

Notes:

- Use [Nightly builds of Fennec](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) for the best experience.
- [Bug 929382](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=929382) tracks WebIDE (née App Manager) integration.
- [File bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox%20for%20Android&component=Web%20Apps) on problems you encounter!

Comment: Because I "need more than 10 reputation to post more than 2 links", here are some links I had to leave out: [mozilla-apk-cli](https://github.com/mozilla/apk-cli), [Nightly builds of Fennec](http://nightly.mozilla.org/), [Bug 929382](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=929382).

Comment: Thanks, that works! Only `mozilla-apk-cli` has [a bug](https://github.com/mozilla/apk-cli/issues/2) in that it doesn't like paths with spaces.